# program not printing result keep saying not defined

Tags: python

Keep getting a not defined error for comm at the second to last print function.
Not sure why the code runs fine until the second to last print function about comm result is asked for.
Everything else is compiling but not the print function

```
while True:
    try:
        sales_person_num = int(input("Please enter ID number "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input. Please enter correct ID number")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        sales_amount = float(input("Please enter sales amount "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input. Please enter correct sales amount")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    try:
        c_lass = int(input("Please enter class "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input. Please enter correct class")
        continue
    else:
        break
    if c_lass == 1:
        if sales_amount <= 1000:
            comm = sales_amount * 0.06
            print(comm)
        elif sales_amount > 1000 and sales_amount < 2000:
            comm =sales_amount * 0.07
            print(comm)
        else:
            comm =sales_amount * 0.1
            print(comm)

    if c_lass == 2:
        if sales_amount < 1000:
            comm = sales_amount * 0.04
            print(comm)
        else:
            comm = sales_amount * 0.06
            print(comm)

    if c_lass == 3:
            comm = sales_amount * 0.045
            print(comm)

print('Your commission is:',comm)
print("Process completed. Have a nice day !") 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
print('Your commission is:',comm)
NameError: name 'comm' is not defined
```

Another thing if I want to just enter 1, 2, or 3 for c_lass variable and anything else incorrect is that fuction correct.

Comment: Please add the traceback for your error to the question.

Comment: `else:  break` exits the `while` loop so nothing after it is executed. Dedent all the `if` blocks one level.

Comment: Side note: with Python, unlike most other languages, you can write `elif 1000 < sales_amount < 2000:`

Comment: Is `sales_amount` defined localy in try-block or globaly?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the else: break should be placed after all the conditions and all if statements shouldn't be indented. Is that right?

Comment: @DominikLovetinsky try-block

Comment: Leave the `else: break` where it is. Just move the `if` blocks to the left so they are not part of the `while` loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp tried that idle shell gave me a syntax error

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it worked with other compilers but not idle shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the part where you do the calculations is inside the `while` block for getting the last input. The calculations should not be part of that `while` because when the user enters correct input the `else: break` is executed and all your calculations are skipped.

I suggest writing a helper function that reads a number from the user. It should not return until valid input is entered. You can also add min/max parameters to clamp the input to a given range. This function will clean up the code a bit.

```
def get_number(prompt, err_msg, convert=int, min_val=None, max_val=None):
    while True:
        try:
            val = convert(input(prompt))
            if min_val != None and val < min_val: continue
            if max_val != None and val > max_val: continue
            return val
        except ValueError:
            print(err_msg)

sales_person_num = get_number("Please enter ID number ", "Incorrect input. Please enter correct ID number")
sales_amount = get_number("Please enter sales amount ", "Incorrect input. Please enter correct sales amount", float)
c_lass = get_number("Please enter class (1-3)", "Incorrect input. Please enter correct class", min_val=1, max_val=3)

if c_lass == 1:
    if sales_amount <= 1000:
        comm = sales_amount * 0.06
    elif 1000 < sales_amount < 2000:
        comm = sales_amount * 0.07
    else:
        comm = sales_amount * 0.1
elif c_lass == 2:
    if sales_amount < 1000:
        comm = sales_amount * 0.04
    else:
        comm = sales_amount * 0.06
else:
    comm = sales_amount * 0.045

print(f"Your commission is: {comm}")
print("Process completed. Have a nice day !")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason for this error is clear: you refer a variable, that is locally defined inside the first try-except block. Move its declaration above it, then it should work as expected:

```
sales_person_num = 0
while True:
    try:
        sales_person_num = int(input("Please enter ID number "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Incorrect input. Please enter correct ID number")
        continue
    else:
        break
# rest of code below here
```

Comment: Tried this, the result kept coming back as 0